# Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

what on earth is wrong with this?
http://jsfiddle.net/sVT54/

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
    function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Your wrong Bergi. That has the same answer, not the same question. I did not know that JSfiddle was the culprit. You can't fault me for not finding that before posting.

Comment: It's the exact same question and answer

Comment: If it was the same question or even similar, my question would be "JSfiddle is not working with my code". I thought my problem WAS my code. If I knew the problem was JSfiddle I would've found that answer.

Comment: "*What on earth is wrong*" is not a good question actually. I'm not faulting you, I'm just giving you a hint. And it should be closed as a dupe when the problem is the same, even if you didn't ask about the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSFiddle wraps your javascript code in the `onLoad` call of the page by default so `myFunction` is defined only in that function's scope. Change to `No wrap - in <head>` and your code will run as expected.

[image: no wrap]

http://jsfiddle.net/sVT54/3/

Answer (score 0):

include your JavaScript in

```
<Script>
 function myFunction()
 {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World";
 }
</script>
```